# is this java blocking queue variant possible?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, blockingqueue

The following scneario is what i was thinking of:
- 2 Threads, 1 Producer, 1 Consumer
- T1 creates the Queue and starts the next thread, and is repsonsible for puting elements into the queue

```
ServerThread implements Runnable{

    run(){
        BlockingQueue q = new ArrayBlockingQueue(1024);
        ListenerThread lt = new ListenerThread8(q);
        lt.start();

        ....

        q.put(message);

    }
}
```

-T2 will wait for elements in the queue and handles them

```
ListenerThread implements Runnable{
        ...
        run(){
            while(run){
               if(!q.isEmpty){
                    sendMessage(q.getfirst());
               }else{
                    sleep(1000);
               }
            }
        }
   }
```

This is just a pseudo implementation of how i want to implement my part of the program.
-Could this work?
-And could this work with the static modifier on the queue?

Comment: May be you should try?

Comment: @Andremoniy When talking about multi-threading, trying is really not enough (though it is needed), due to [heisenbugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug), and theoretical analysis is needed.

Comment: It is better to use Concurrent Queue it is Thread Safe

Comment: You need to make sure you either used `synchronized` blocks or else use concurrent data structures when reading/writing from the queue.

Comment: @Andremoniy I am unexperienced in multithreading and read an article from jenkov, so i like to get some knowledge from advanced users before starting right of. I have a bit limited testing slack at my current environment

Comment: @npinti - [BlockingQueue implementations are thread-safe](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the natural pattern for producer-consumer so yes this will work.

By the way - you don't need to check the queue to see if it is empty - you just need to call `take` which will wait until something is there.

```
class Thing {
}

class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        BlockingQueue<Thing> q = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1024);
        ListenerThread lt = new ListenerThread(q);
        new Thread(lt).start();

        q.put(message);

    }
}

class ListenerThread implements Runnable {

    volatile boolean run;
    private final BlockingQueue<Thing> q;

    public ListenerThread (BlockingQueue<Thing> q) {
        this.q = q;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (run) {
            try {
                sendMessage(q.take());
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                run = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You should not need to make the queue `static`.

The only adjustment I would recommend would be to not create the listener inside the server `run` method. The server should know as little as possible about the consumer. The queue, the server and the consumer should all be created and linked up someplace else.

Comment: You _can't_ make a queue `static`.  @Gobliins, There is no such thing as a `static` queue. You can have a `static` _variable_ that references a queue, but that has no effect whatsoever on how the queue behaves when it is accessed by different threads.

Comment: @jameslarge Yes, the thing i was looking for seems to be InheritableThreadLocal

Comment: @Gobliins - Are you sure you need an `InheritableThreadLocal` - they are used in [very obscure](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t54279.html) circumstances.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon The problem was, i need a static variable but this variable should only be accesible in two referenced threads. With threadLocal i had only a copy of this variable but not the reference to the same variable at all.